# Trying make a role be in a list but getting weird error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is the snippet of my code that i'm trying to get working (I have already defined `rgb[]` at the start of the code):

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True,description="Linusifies a role")
   client.command(pass_context=True,description="Linusifies a role")
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rgb(ctx, role : discord.Role):
    if role in rgb:
        msg = "{}'s rgb is turned off :disappointed_relieved:"
        rgb.remove(role)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
    else:
        msg = "{}'s rgb has been turned on :christmas_tree:".format(role)
        rgb.append(role)
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
```

And this is the error that spits out when I try and do #rgb @role in the server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in rgb
TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable
```

Comment: You can't have `rgb` as both the name of a list, and the name of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @jasonharper the name of the command conflicted with the list

fixed code:

`@client.command(pass_context=True,description="Linusifies a role")
@has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def rgb(ctx, role : discord.Role):
    if role in rgb_list:
        msg = "{}'s rgb is turned off :disappointed_relieved:".format(role)
        rgb_list.remove(role)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
    else:
        msg = "{}'s rgb has been turned on :christmas_tree:".format(role)
        rgb_list.append(role)
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)`